# What's the meaning of "you should worry" in the following lines from Pinter's Birthday Party?

Tags: meaning, harold-pinter, the-birthday-party

What's the meaning of "you should worry" in the following lines from Pinter's Birthday Party (emphasis mine)?

> LULU. You’re tickling me!
>
> GOLDBERG. **You should worry.**
>
> LULU. I’ve always liked older men. They can soothe you.
>
> They embrace.